# Is this wrong in MSDN document?

Tags: c++, c, microprocessors

Here is MSDN link
From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(v=VS.80).aspx

It says:
unsigned int : 4byte 
Range of Value 0 to **4,294,967,295**

Hence my test code:

```
void main(void) 
{       
    unsigned int sum;   //4byte, 32bit
    sum = 2147483648;  //2^31 represent by 1 followed by 31 0s
    printf("sum is %d\n",sum); 
    sum = sum -1 ;     //2^31-1 represent by 0 followed by 31 1s
    printf("sum is %d\n",sum);
    getchar();
}
```

I am sure 4,294,967,295=2^32-1, printf will print "0", dump most significant bit
I think MSDN should wrote range of value: 0 to **2147483647**
Is that right?

Comment: Use `%u` instead of `%d`.  The latter is for printing signed int.

Comment: You probably want to use `%u` instead of `%d` since you're trying to print an `unsigned int`. I think that will clear up some of your confusion.

Comment: No, an unsigned int uses all of its bits. None are "dumped".

Comment: Here is perhaps a better example:  http://ideone.com/rSR0C

Comment: `main` returns an `int`. And just to be clear, MSDN information applies to specific compilers and platforms, so this isn't universally true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's incorrect, if you want to get 4b you should do

```
unsigned int sum;
sum = 0;
sum -= 1;
```

Alternatively

```
unsigned int sum = -1; // will give the same result
```

This should give you the correct max value for an unsigned int (as hackish as that is). Also as others pointed out you should use %u as the formatter in your printf so that the value gets interpreted correctly.

An unsigned int uses all bits as magnitude bits so the leading bit is no longer considered a sign bit so that becomes 2^32 - 1 instead of just 2^31 - 1

Comment: Why don't you simply write this >> `unsigned int sum = -1`?

Comment: @Nawaz: Because he wrote it the same way (with a different number though)

Answer (score 6):

The documentation is correct.

-2147483648 to 2147483647 (2<sup>31</sup> - 1) is the range of a *signed* int.

0 to 4294967295 (2<sup>32</sup> - 1) is the range of an *unsigned* int.

Use `%u` instead of `%d`

```
printf("sum is %u\n",sum);
```

See [printf Type Field Characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: -2147483648 to 2147483647 is the range of a signed int.

Comment: @Mitch, your answer is correct but his value is wrong if he wants to print the max of the unsigned int. I'm not really sure what he's trying to do there.

Answer (score 0):

As Sander mentioned, you need to use `%u` instead of `%d` since you are looking at unsigned integers instead of signed.

Negative numbers are stored using [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) where -1 = 0xFFFFFFFF, -2 = 0xFFFFFFFE, and so on to -2^32 = 0x80000000.

You would get an overflow (dumping the extra bit) if you did 0xFFFFFFFF + 1 to an unsigned int, with the result in the variable being 0.